# SFML Packet and Arduino

Tags: ethernet, networking

Can the [`sf::Packet`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1Packet.php) class of SFML-network be ported over to arduino for use with the Ethernet library or would it be too big? I'm working on a client-program where an arduino is a server and a regular computer is the client making a request. I'm using the SFML-network library to make networking easier on myself and would prefer to use the built in features of SFML to make networking easier. If it is not feasible would I be better off using fixed width data to communicate with the arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how it all works, my guess is that you would have to port the whole of SFML, which would be **HUGE**.  So, "No!" is the answer.

You could, of course, write a library of your own that had an SFML-like interface, but the Arduino networking libraries are already pretty simplistic and easy to use, so what's the point?

Comment: I'm sending complex packets that must be deconstructed in a specific way. So I would prefer to have a way to send and receive data in such a way that it will always be the same.

Comment: That's what *struct*s are for.